# Not able to disable UIBarButtonItem in UIToolabar

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I use code similar to following code make a custom toolbar. But it disabling functionality not working,

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(navigationCart:)];
    barButtonItem.image = [self imageCartIconNormal];
    barButtonItem.enabled = NO;

[self setToolbarItems:[[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:barButtonItem,barButtonItem1, barButtonItem2, nil] animated:YES];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working :

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];
button.enabled  = NO;
button.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
[self.toolbar setItems:@[button] animated:YES];
```

Make sure your `imageCartIconNormal` returns a `UIImage`.
Make sure your `setToolbarItems` calls the method above on an `UIToolbar`.

NB: There is no use in a mutable array here.

Comment: Yes it should be work, but not in my code. what can be cause for this problem

Comment: Just copy my code and it will work. You are hiding your code, so nobody knows what is the problem. Also I wrote what could be the cause for the problem.